# validate text box input (for fasta format) before submission

Tags: javascript, php, fasta

I want to validate a text box input on an HTML page whether it is in `fasta` format or not and if it only contains one sequence before submission of data.

I know PHP and little idea about JavaScript.
I don't think it is possible with php.

Comment: You have to check it on the server side (`php`), since you should never trust data from the client. The `JavaScript` validation is optional and only reduces server load and provides better user feedback. But server-side validation is essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to validate it using JavaScript, you can use the following function:

```
/*
 * Validates (true/false) a single fasta sequence string
 * param   fasta    the string containing a putative single fasta sequence
 * returns boolean  true if string contains single fasta sequence, false 
 *                  otherwise 
 */
function validateFasta(fasta) {

    if (!fasta) { // check there is something first of all
        return false;
    }

    // immediately remove trailing spaces
    fasta = fasta.trim();

    // split on newlines... 
    var lines = fasta.split('\n');

    // check for header
    if (fasta[0] == '>') {
        // remove one line, starting at the first position
        lines.splice(0, 1);
    }

    // join the array back into a single string without newlines and 
    // trailing or leading spaces
    fasta = lines.join('').trim();

    if (!fasta) { // is it empty whatever we collected ? re-check not efficient 
        return false;
    }

    // note that the empty string is caught above
    // allow for Selenocysteine (U)
    return /^[ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTUVWY\s]+$/i.test(fasta);
}
```

Source: http://www.blopig.com/blog/2013/03/a-javascript-function-to-validate-fasta-sequences/

Note, however, that you should perform the same check on the server side with `php`. The languages are very similar, and php provides everything you need.

Comment: I implement your script but it is not working. As I wrote I know little javascript. Could you please let me know my mistake. here is html code:     
<form action="submit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea align=center type="text" id="protein_seq" name="protein_seq" row='80' cols='100'></textarea> 
<input id="button1" type="submit" onclick="validateFasta('protein_seq')" value="Submit" /> 
</form>

Comment: Your code is currently validating the string `protein_seq`, not the text-box input. Use `fasta = document.getElementById(fasta).value;` in the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the script that I modified as per my needs and it's working very well in mine case.

-----java script------

```
function validate(){

var seq = $("#protein_seq").val();

if (!seq) { 

 alert("No input"); 

// check there is something first of all
    return false;
}


seq = seq.trim();

// split on newlines... 
var lines = seq.split('\n');

// check for header
if (seq[0] == '>') {

    // remove one line, starting at the first position  
    lines.splice(0, 1);
 if (lines[0] ==undefined) {

   alert("Please enter amino acid sequence in second line"); 
} 
}
else{ alert("First line should start with '>' and amino-acid sequence in next line. Please refer to example data");  
    //The seq string contains non-DNA characters
    return false;}

// join the array back into a single string without newlines and 
// trailing or leading spaces
seq = lines.join('').trim();

//Search for charaters that are not G, A, T or C.
if (seq.search(/[^ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTUVWY\s]/i) != -1) { 

    alert("Unspecified amino acid seq");  
    //The seq string contains non-protein characters
    return false;

 }
```

---------html page-------------------------------------

```
 <form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate()"><br><textarea align=center type="text"  id='protein_seq' name="protein_seq" row='80' cols='100'></textarea><br> 
<input id="button1" type="submit" class="myButton"  value="Submit" />
```